# Replace part of a cell value with blank with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a spread sheet where `Column A` has a list of computer names with `domain\` preceding the computer name. I am trying to use `openpyxl` to remove the `domain\` and leave just the computer names. Here is the code I have tried. There is no error however the script does not change anything on the spreadsheet.

```py
import openpyxl
    excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file.xlsx')
    sheet1 = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    currentRow = 1
    for eachRow in sheet1.iter_rows():
        if sheet1.cell(row=currentRow, column=1).value == "'domain\'":
            sheet1.cell(row=currentRow, column=1).value = ""
        currentRow += 1
    excelFile.save('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace the cell value with a trimmed string.

```py
import openpyxl
filename = r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\file.xlsx'
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet1 = excelFile.active
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if 'domain\\' in cell.value:
            cell.value = cell.value[7:] #This will replace the cell value with a trimmed string
excelFile.save(filename)
```

Comment: No need to count. `if str_to_remove in cell.value: cell.value = cell.value.replace(str_to_replace, "")`